# How to code basic search in my website in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I want to code a basic search box in my php based online shopping website. the problem is the data is in 50 tables categorised based on product type.
ie 
table 1 - Mobile Phones
table 2 - Laptops 
table 50 - Air Conditioners

i can code it using query like
select * from table 1 
if 0 rows returned
select * from table 2
if 0 rows returned
next
till table 50

but this code can slow down the website as each keypress will lead into 100 queries execution is there anything else i can do about it ?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible database design...

Comment: If this website is yours, better consider to combine data and perform better database design i.e., not to use separate table for each category, but to have one table with all categories and one for all products, related with primary/foreign key(s).

Comment: Sir I am just a noob

Comment: I agree with changing schema, but for the sake of not being able to, Could your user select the category prior to the search?  If so you could test a variable of the category to know which table to query. Also if you truly only want results from one table the key will be a stored procedure and the "RETRUN" that way once you find what you want you will just get out of the procedure.  If you do this start with the most popular category downward to increase the chance that you will get the results in the first or first couple of queries.

Comment: I agree with @Siyual. Maybe what you need is a change of database design. Not one table per category, but one table for products and secondary tables for categories, colors, subtypes, etc. You would only search in the products table. I guess there are many ways to redesign your database to make it more efficient.

Comment: Sir changing Database schema is not possible for me cause I will also have to change the whole website which has more than 30K lines of code.
I know this is poorly designed website but since It's my first project without any support or help i considered making tables for each category I added to the site.

Comment: In that case, maybe a huge inner join of 50 tables would do it. And thanks for calling me "sir".

Comment: Sir I am sure using join will make site slow will it? 

what if I make a procedure that will pull out data from all tables ie names and category and put them in new table and use this table to search website ?
I can call this procedure once a day so the product added will be available after 24 hours.

how is this idea?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sir I ended up with Normalisation not possible to change 30kloc , use union or join both are slow using sorted array slow as well,
What else option do I have?

Comment: Rishabh, your idea is good : an extra table to store only names and categories. You will only have to update that table maybe once a week (depends on your site traffic).

Comment: Sir Jose Whats if I search in the table if 0 rows return run the porcess of update table then search again ? This may slow down the search for a user but other will get updated search resuls

Answer (score -1):

Options:

**1)** Normalise your tables so there's just one table to search (may be difficult if different products have different fields)

**2)** Use SQL Unions (can be very slow):

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

**3)** Query each table, store results in array, use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to sort the array and then output them.

Comment: Sir what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: Sort your table design out if you can, 50 tables for different types of products is ludicrous.

Comment: Sir I can But I can't cause I will have to change all codes which is more than 30KLOC 

what if I make a procedure that will pull out data from all tables ie names and category and put them in new table and use this table to search website ?
I can call this procedure once a day so the product added will be available after 24 hours.

how is this idea?

Comment: @RishabhGusain So search results can be up to 24 hours out of date? I wouldn't recommend it, but it sounds as though you're going to be forced into making a compromise. Whether you use your time to fix it from the start by redoing your code, or you spend viewers time by slow search results, would be down to you.